# Use swagger specification in GoLang for Azure functions

Tags: azure, go, swagger, serverless-framework

Curently i'm building an Azure serverless Function in GoLang. I must have a swagger specification inside the function.
I'm using gin as http framework and [swaggo](https://github.com/swaggo/swag) as the swagger specification generator.

Main function:

```
func main() {
    port, exists := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT")
    if !exists {
        port = "8080"
    }
    r := gin.Default()

    v1 := r.Group("/api")
    v1.GET("/ping", function.Ping)
    v1.GET("/docs", function.Swagger)
    url := ginSwagger.URL("http://localhost:7071/api/docs")
    v1.GET("/swagger", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler, url))
    r.Run(":" + port)
}
```

The function that will return the swagger.json:

```
func Swagger(c *gin.Context) {
    c.File("docs/swagger.json")
}
```

When we build the application and run it local the response is 404.

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting that's returning a 404?

Comment: The /api/swagger endpoint @disposedtrolley

Comment: The [gin-swagger docs](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger#canonical-example) say that `ginSwagger.URL` should be provided with the URL to the API definition. Should that be `http://localhost:8080/api/docs` instead?

Comment: I created the endpoint /api/docs for exposing the swagger json file. Because a serverless function can't reach the static files.

Comment: So is the `FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT` env var set when you're running locally? Otherwise I think you might be getting a 404 because `"http://localhost:7071/api/docs"` is hitting port 7071 and port 8080 is being used instead.